# Getting CORS Error when using fetch to get data

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to access the API to get some data however i keep getting this CORS error. I have checked my code for any syntax errors but i can't find any. I have attached a picture of the error and my function which is supposed to get the data.

[image: CORS Error]

```
async function getData(){
  const request = await fetch('https://api.igdb.com/v4/games', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Client-ID': 'jglmao8u28qo1p9wltqne325i7xh3u',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 4xau27m6liukizor4z2l8mlb7vbpjk',
  }
  })
  const response = await request.json();
  console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider not providing your client ID and bearer token to the world.

Comment: It is fine i will generate a new one once my problem is solved.

Comment: There is a section in the API documentation of IGDB about CORS. https://api-docs.igdb.com/#cors For a better understanding of why this is happening I suggest checking out [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35553500/3982562) which has an excellent answer that explains the issue using an example scenario.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is a great proxy out there used just for this - bypassing a CORS block. The source code is here: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere, and you would use it like this:

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.igdb.com/v4/games`
basically just adding the CORS-Anywhere URL before your actual image URL.

In your situation, it would be

```js
async function getData(){
  const request = await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.igdb.com/v4/games', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Client-ID': 'jglmao8u28qo1p9wltqne325i7xh3u',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 4xau27m6liukizor4z2l8mlb7vbpjk',
  }
  })
  const response = await request.json();
  console.log(response);
}
```

If you get rate limited by that website, try `https://circumvent-cors.herokuapp.com/`, this is one that I have deployed from the GitHub source code, no modifications and I do not think it should rate limit you.

Cheers, and let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am getting this error now POST https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.igdb.com/v4/games 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: try `https://circumvent-cors.herokuapp.com/https://api.igdb.com/v4/games`

Comment: That seemed to have worked however i am getting an empty array for some reason. I might need to check the docs to see correct endpoints.

Comment: Your solution has fixed the problem. The reason i was getting an empty array was because i had to specify the data i needed in the body. This is my first time i have come across such an API where you need to do that. It is for sure different from other APIs that i have used. Anyways thank you for the solution.